# Effect on loading UserControl in ContentPresenter

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard

I have a page with a ContentPresenter where I load different UserControls.
I need to set an effect on the ContentPresenter (any effect) so when I load an UserControl to animate it.
Now I've made a StoryBoard on the loaded event with a simple ScaleTransform but it's on UserControl.
Can I put it on ContentPresenter so it has a ScaleTransform for every UserControl that will be loaded in it ?
Thanks

Comment: How? That's my question. On user control I've put it in Onload. But in ContentPresenter ?